# Select from 2 tables in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a problem with my select, so I have 2 tables:

```
category
id    name
product
id  name  category_id
```

Now I want to select products for one category:

```
public function getCategory($cat_id)
{
    return View::make('store.category')
        ->with('products', Product::where('category_id', '=' , $cat_id))
}
```

This query is empty, exists another solution??Help me please.

Comment: run the query with `get()`, otherwise you pass `Eloquent\Builder` object instead of the collection of fetched results.

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't built quite right. You aren't calling `get()` on the query, so its not actually running. And also, you aren't passing the products quite right. Try this

```
public function getCategory($cat_id)
{
    $products = Product::where('category_id', '=' , $cat_id)->get();

    return View::make('store.category')
        ->with(array('products' => $products));
}
```